# systemverilog, how to handle reset?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

The systemverilog `semaphore` is really half baked.

I could not find any way to release the semaphores in case of a `reset`, something like `.flush()` for `uvm_tlm_fifo`?

There is also no method to know how many semaphores are locked?

Is there some wrapper available in `UVM` something like `uvm_event` which extends the basic semaphore functionality?

People suggested me to use mailbox/tlm_fifo for more functionality, but i could not find an alternate to semaphore for allocating more than 1 `keyCount`.

If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemVerilog's semaphore and mailbox are basic built-in classes that you can extend to suit your needs. Semaphores provide the basic key locking and unlocking mechanisms, but it is up to you to manage the keys.

---

What I meant was you can extend or encapsulate the semaphore to control who has access to the keys and how many keys are in use.

Answer (score 1):

Just kill all the old threads relate to that semaphore, create a new semaphore in its place and forget about the old one.  It is probably an easier way to deal with reset than trying to clean up the old running threads.